# Google Sheet formula on finding smallest value larger than 0 does not work inside conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function

I wanted to find and highlight the smallest value larger than 0, but the formula I am using does not work in the conditional formatting.

```
 =MIN(FILTER(L4:L100, (L4:L100)>0))
```

Namely, if I use it inside the sheet, it will find value 0.44 and write it out.

[image]

However, if I used it in the conditional formatting, it will mark ALL values larger than 0.

[image]

[image]

Anyone knows why the formula does not work in the conditional formatting?

Comment: Thanks for this question, it's the solution to my problem. :) The formula you entered here already works great for finding the lowest number (in a range) that is higher than a provided number.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution out of sudden. I have forgotten (did knot know it was needed) to add another condition.

The correct formula is:

```
 =L4:L100=MIN(FILTER(L4:L100, (L4:L100)>0),1)
```